# UIPageViewController delegate, dataSource, & interface error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am developing an app that uses an UIPageViewController so that I may swipe from left to right to navigate through the pages (ViewControllers). Since my original post, I have written code. But I am receiving three errors.

Error 1: Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'IntroPages'
Error 2: Property 'dataSource' not found on object of type 'IntroPages'
Error 3: No visible @interface for 'IntroPages' declares the selector 'setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:'

All three errors are in the first section (section being in the {} braces) of the viewDidLoad. The first two are for the code right under viewDidLoad and the third 5 lines down.

The delegate and dataSource are referenced on the .h file. Why are they not being found? Wy is there no visible @interface for 'IntroPages'?

Code is below.

IntroPages.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IntroPages : UIViewController
<UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@end
```

IntroPages.m

```
#import "IntroPages.h"

@interface IntroPages ()

@end

@implementation IntroPages
{
    NSArray *myViewControllers;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.delegate = self; 
    self.dataSource = self;

    UIViewController *p1 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Intro1ID"];
    UIViewController *p2 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Intro2ID"];
    UIViewController *p3 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Intro3ID"];
    UIViewController *p4 = [self.storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Intro4ID"];

    myViewControllers = @[p1,p2,p3,p4];

    [self setViewControllers:@[p1]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"loaded!");
}


@end
```

Comment: so what is the issue ur facing .... and what u tried ...? post ur code.

Comment: I edited the post with where I am at. Code is included.

Answer (score 0):

If the pages aren't too numerous, you can create an array of view controllers with an array of their ids, like this:

```
// assuming this
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pages;

// then, to setup, say these are the page ids...
NSArray *vcIds = @[ @"id0", @"id1", ... ];
self.pages = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *vcId in vcIds) {
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:vcId];
    [self.pages addObject:vc];
}

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:self.pages direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

[UIPageViewControllerDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdatasource?language=objc) requests view controllers before and after a given vc.  Get the correct result by looking up the passed vc in the pages array...

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = [self.pages indexOfObject:viewController];
    return (index)? self.pages[index-1] : 0;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = [self.pages indexOfObject:viewController];
    return (index<self.pages.count-1)? self.pages[index+1] : self.pages[self.pages.count-1];
}
```

Comment: There would only 5 pages in the array.

The code you offered is similar to what I saw in a tutorial. That tutorial had titles and images in an array, but they weren't actually assigned to a VC. They were just pulled from the array to create a vc. I assumed that calling actual vcs from an array would be similar. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that a story board using this would include original view controller -> page view controller -> any views that would be called from array?

Comment: @thejdah, yes. in fact, we get the storyboard in the suggested code with `self.storyboard`, so that requires that the vc that is `self` is defined in the same storyboard as the vcs which have those ids.  If you need to define the vcs in different storyboards, let me know, and I can show you how to do that

Comment: All of this would be in the implementation file?

Comment: Yes, though the properties go in the interface, which may be in your .m file or .h file

Comment: It looks like you've edited your question to include an unrolled version of the loop I suggested.  I think I'm going to abandon trying to help here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to piece everything together. I'm not experienced in this at all. I edited the question because I was marked down for the original question. Thanks for the help.